# Database searching with R

Tags: r

I have database with 24000 rows and 4 columns as follow :

```
 mydata<-read.csv("data.csv", header=T, sep=',',  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = FALSE)
 p<- read.csv("datab.csv",  header = TRUE, sep = ";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = FALSE )

> mydata

          ID     TF   score
1 hsa-let-7a-1 RORA2   878
2 hsa-let-8c-1  AML1  1000
3 hsa-let-5f-1  ZIC1   994
4 hsa-let-7a-1  ZIC2   968
.               .      .
.               .      .
```

and I have vector `p`

```
str(p)
Factor w/ 16 levels "hsa-miR-150",..: 16 14 3
>p
hsa-let-7a-1
hsa-miR-92a  
hsa-miR-425   
hsa-miR-192
```

I want to get  subset of `mydata` which `ID` in `mydata` exist in `p`
I used this code :

```
out <- subset(mydata, ID %in% p)
```

but it didn't retrieve subset of `mydata` when I'm was sure that some elements of `p` exist in `ID`
I've got flowing output when I was certain that some elements of `p` exist in `ID` (I added by myself for testing)

```
> out
[1] ID     TF     score  zScore
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

can somebody help me where is my mistake. whether it could be due to large size of database ?

Comment: I believe the issue is around p (and possible ID) being factors as opposed to characters - if you convert both, it will ensure that it's doing a string comparison as opposed to a level comparison.

Comment: @Steph Locke, I should convert mydata and p to string ? how ?

Comment: `mydata<-read.csv("data.csv", header=T, sep=',',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and `p<-as.character(p)`

Comment: @StephLocke I did so and both of them now are char . but still doesn't work ! :P  , my vector P<- read.csv2("spot.csv", header=T, sep=";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) also mydata<-read.csv("data.csv", header=T, sep=',',stringsAsFactors = FALSE) , but still I couldn't get subset of mydata

Comment: Great, you may need to check for excess whitespace in your strings.  You can also look to see if it's a problem with your subset statement or the codes by doing `mydata$ID %in% p`

Comment: @StephLocke , How can I check and remove white spaces in my string? (mydata and p) . I checked my code, it'w work with simple examples. but i think the problem might be due to white spaces in string.

Comment: You might have a look at the `strip.white` argument in `read.table`.

Comment: ...and/or `str_trim` in package `stringr`

Comment: I removed, but still my code doesn't work :P

Comment: @user2806363 Can you add the results of `dput(head(mydata,50))` and `dput(head(p,50))` onto pastebucket.com and include a link?

Comment: Well, take it slowly. After reading in each array, test the `class` of each and every column.  In parallel (so to speak), create two small arrays manually with the column names you desire, and verify that `subset` does what you expect with this test set.

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra parentheses on second line of your code and change the value of `strip.white`, `strip.white = TRUE`.

```
mydata <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, sep=',', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
p <- read.csv("datab.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

The variable `p` is a data.frame, so you have to include the column name.

```
out <- subset(mydata, ID %in% p$name)
```